# What is a scalable way to create this NHibernate Domain Model

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, class-design

I have a situation where I have two kinds of customers. Person and Organization. There are some attributes that Person has that organization does not need (eg: First Name, Last Name etc). Then there are some organization attributes that Person does not need (eg: Company Name etc). But in the domain of the software both Person and Company are customers.

Question: Is it better to dump all attributes in one domain object called Customer and differentiate between person and org using a bool like IsOrganization??
OR
Is it better to have a Person domain class , Organization domain class and Customer domain class that contains Person and Organization properties.

I feel latter is the way to go but I am open to ideas.
Customer - Person relationship is 0 to n where n=1
Customer - Organization relationship is also 0 to n where n=1

If it helps, I am using NHibernate and FluentNHibernate. Taking the code first approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second approach is the way to go.  You can set up your domain model having Customer as an abstract base class that has all of the common properties of Person and Organization, and having Person and Organization as both being subclasses of Customer with each subclass having the properties that are specific to them.  I think this would be an accurate model your business domain.

As far as how to set this up in the database so that nHibernate can map this inheritance hierarchy from the data schema to the object model, you have three options:

```
1) table per class hierarchy
2) table per subclass
3) table per concrete class
```

These are described further in the [nHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a Person and Organization classes and an ICustomer interface that defines the contract for the in-common properties and methods. Inheritance isn't a good choice because a there's no "is-a" relationship between the two classes.

Comment: So if I have tables per Person and Organization.. i wont be able to use ID (autoincrement) as customer number within the app. Right?